# Extract specific information from string typed date column using SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a date column in my table which is unfortunately in strings and has an inconsistent format(it has a mixed format).

for e.x:

for month march, day 1, year 2022 date can be represented in

-> 1-3-22 or 01-03-2022

how can I extract the day, month, and year separately from the date column?

**description:**

table name -> employee

column I'm focusing on -> date -> type-> string

language -> SQL

DB -> MySQL

Comment: Please only tag a **single** not multiple.

Comment: As per the question guide please show what you have tried

Comment: Did you try [searching](https://www.google.com/search?q=MySQL+date+parse&oq=MySQL+date+parse) before posting? Or reading the [Date and Time Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) help for MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL you can use the [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) functions to parse a string into a date type, then use the [DAYOFMONTH](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofmonth), [MONTH](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) and [YEAR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) functions to extract the components of interest.

For example, on current MySQL 8.x versions, using [LATERAL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lateral-derived-tables.html) to simulate an OUTER APPLY, you can do this:

```sql
create table Example (
  Stringy varchar(10)
);

insert Example (Stringy) values ('1-3-22'), ('01-03-2022');

select Stringy, Datey, dayofmonth(Datey) "Day", month(Datey) "Month", year(Datey) "Year"
from Example
left join lateral (
  select str_to_date(Stringy, '%d-%m-%Y') "Datey"
) S2D on 1=1;
```

Which returns the results:

| Stringy | Datey | Day | Month | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1-3-22 | 2022-03-01 | 1 | 3 | 2022 |
| 01-03-2022 | 2022-03-01 | 1 | 3 | 2022 |

Answer (score -1):

your data is string value with this form 'Day-Month-Year' that is separated by **-**, In **MySQL** you can use *SUBSTRING_INDEX* to split string based on charterer and change it into your desired result

```
-- a test data '01-03-2022'
SELECT
  SUBSTRING_INDEX('01-03-2022','-', -1) AS year1,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('01-03-2022', '-', 2),'-', -1) AS month1, 
  SUBSTRING_INDEX('01-03-2022','-', 1) AS day1
```

In **SQL Server** use _PARSENAME(REPLACE) as follows

```
-- a test data '01-03-2022'
SELECT  
PARSENAME(REPLACE('01-03-2022' ,'-','.'),1) year1,
PARSENAME(REPLACE('01-03-2022' ,'-','.'),2) month1,
PARSENAME(REPLACE('01-03-2022' ,'-','.'),3) day1
```